# How to update mosquitto to latest version in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, version, updates, mosquitto

I have installed `mosquitto` in `ubuntu` using command:

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto
```

The mosquitto installed is version 1.6.9.

```
mosquitto version 1.6.9

mosquitto is an MQTT v3.1.1 broker.

Usage: mosquitto [-c config_file] [-d] [-h] [-p port]

 -c : specify the broker config file.
 -d : put the broker into the background after starting.
 -h : display this help.
 -p : start the broker listening on the specified port.
      Not recommended in conjunction with the -c option.
 -v : verbose mode - enable all logging types. This overrides
      any logging options given in the config file.

See http://mosquitto.org/ for more information
```

In order to update the mosquitto to latest version, I first uninstalled it and then ran command `sudo apt-get update` and then reinstalled the mosquitto but the version was still the same.

How can I update mosquitto to latest version.?

Comment: I suspect that it isn't obvious how it's a programming question

Comment: which  version of ubuntu are you using ? is it an LTS version like 18.04 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a more recent version of `mosquitto` but you are on an old version of Ubuntu then by reading the official download page [here](https://mosquitto.org/download/) you can find that there is more than one approach to install the latest mosquitto version :

1. Compiling and building directly from source, i wouldn't recommend doing this (especially for beginners).
2. Using the `mosquitto-dev PPA`.
3. Using snap packages instead of apt by simply running `sudo snap install mosquitto`

**However** i think the best way to go is by using the `mosquitto-dev PPA` as  building mosquitto from source take more time and effort, and using snap involves more steps to get it up and running.

**So**.. First uninstall the old mosquitto version:

```
sudo apt autoremove mosquitto
```

then you need to add `mosquitto-dev PPA` to your sources list :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa 
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install mosquitto:

```
sudo apt install mosquitto
```

Verify your installation by simply running `mosquitto --help`, the output should be something like this :

```
mosquitto version 2.0.10

mosquitto is an MQTT v5.0/v3.1.1/v3.1 broker.

Usage: mosquitto [-c config_file] [-d] [-h] [-p port]

 -c : specify the broker config file.
 -d : put the broker into the background after starting.
 -h : display this help.
 -p : start the broker listening on the specified port.
      Not recommended in conjunction with the -c option.
 -v : verbose mode - enable all logging types. This overrides
      any logging options given in the config file.

See https://mosquitto.org/ for more information.
```

**Congrats** Now you have the latest release installed.